# Google Services is not searching for google-services.json file in Android app module?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on a multi-module project for Android.

I have the `google-services.json` file in the `:app` module. However, when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

Now, the traceback says Google Services searched a separate module `:core:data` which does use Firebase.

Both the `:app` module and `:core:data` module contain the Google Services plugin and necessary Firebase dependencies.

Any idea on what is going on? How can I change where Google Services searches for the `google-services.json` file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had added the Google Services plugin into both the `:app` and `:core:data` modules when it should only be in the `:app` module.